# how to send notification from one device to another

Tags: android

Currently I am trying to implement a feature where if I do some action in my app on one android device (changing channel on android tv), it should trigger my another android device in close proximity to launch one of its application.

I was just wondering which could be the easiest way to prototype it? Should I need to send some kind of push notification or another simple solution is possible? I just need it for prototyping as of now.

Thanks

Comment: but application remains same for both devices ?

Comment: @DROIDcoder no it has to be different application for mobile device which start when the notification is sent.

Comment: so you want to start a new application based on another actions ?

Comment: @DROIDcoder .. yes. like once I change channel on android tv, it should trigger to start an app on android phone/tablet nearby

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) with XMPP protocol that allows device-to-cloud connection. In the documentation you will find examples, just read it through.

This technique is very often called device to device but it's actually about upstreaming to the server and telling the server to push notification.

Requirement for both apps would be to use the same [GCM sender ID](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html).

Since this is a prototype you don't actually need to check if device is close to you or not. Otherwise, you could frequently update device's location on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to develop a application like airdroid

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en

As i know it set up small http server in one phone. And Send request from an another device. As you want. This sample help you to create such kind of http server. There is one restriction both device must be in same network.

https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd.